# How to extract all the values in a specific key in a list of object

Tags: javascript, angular

i have the list posted below in the code. the list is composed of two keys `centerPoint` and `distanceToTreatment`
as shown below i populate the list with some values in a loop and then i sort the list as shown below. what i want to do is, given the list `list` and the values it contains, i would like to have an array containg only the values in the
key `centerPoints`

in other words, i would like to have an array containing only the values in `centerPoint`.so, list contains 50 entry and i would like to have an array contains all the 50 values in the key `centerPoint`

please let me know how extract all the values contained in a specific key in an array.

**code**:

```
let list:Array<{centerPoint:string, distanceToTreatment:number}> = Array()
for(let i = 0; i < this.arrayOfDistancesFromCenterToTreatmen.length;i++) {
list.push({centerPoint: this.arrayOfCenterPointsAsGeoJSON[i], distanceToTreatment:this.arrayOfDistancesFromCenterToTreatmen[i]})
}
list.sort((a,b) => (a.distanceToTreatment > b.distanceToTreatment) ? 1 : ((b.distanceToTreatment > a.distanceToTreatment) ? -1 : 0))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const centerPoints = list.map(l => l.centerPoint);
```